# Pyspark - Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o102.collectToPython

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with [this](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/u-s-chronic-disease-indicators-cdi) data locally with jupyter lab. My spark crashes when I try to do a ranking. I increased my java memory using [this tutorial](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/wikihow/index.php/How_to_Increase_Java_Memory_in_Windows) too. I don't understand what is going on, I suppose that it's a problem with the drive memory, but why? This is something that I would do easily using pandas. I checked my memory and it doesn't go more that 64% of what I have.

```
### Spark ###
# To find out where the pyspark
import findspark
findspark.init()

# Creating Spark Context
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, FloatType

### Working with data ###
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

### Visualization ###
import altair as alt

### Utils ###
import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen

# File format #
import csv
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Geolocation #
import geopy

sc = SparkContext("local", "Testing")

spark = SQLContext(sc)

# Get city name
def get_place(lat, lon):
    geo_key = '' # get key here https://developer.mapquest.com/plan_purchase/steps/business_edition/business_edition_free/register
    geolocator = geopy.geocoders.OpenMapQuest(api_key=geo_key)
    location = geolocator.geocode("%s, %s" % (lat, lon))
    return location.address.split(',')[-3][1:] # Getting city and removing space

# Get lat
def get_lat(str_in):
    return (str_in[1:-1].split(',')[0])

def get_lon(str_in):
    return (str_in[1:-1].split(',')[1])

# parallelize function to be used with spark
pl_get_place = F.udf(get_place, StringType())
pl_get_lat = F.udf(get_lat, StringType())
pl_get_lon = F.udf(get_lon, StringType())

df = spark.read.csv("data/U.S._Chronic_Disease_Indicators__CDI_.csv", sep=',', header=True)

df_location = df.filter("GeoLocation IS NOT NULL")

# creating latitude and longitude
df_location = (
    df_location
    .withColumn('lat', pl_get_lat(F.col('GeoLocation')))
    .withColumn('lon', pl_get_lon(F.col('GeoLocation')))
)

df_location = (
    df_location
    .withColumn("city", pl_get_place(F.col('lat'), F.col('lon')))
)

top_10_window = Window.partitionBy('Topic').orderBy(F.col('DataValue').desc())

top_10_cities = (
    df_location.select('Topic', 'city', 'DataValue', F.rank().over(top_10_window).alias('rank')) 
    .filter(F.col('rank') <= 10)
)

to_n_ranks_cities = (
    top_10_cities
    .groupBy('city')
    .agg(F.countDistinct('Topic').alias('num_times_top'))
).toPandas()
```

Error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:172)
2019-03-12 15:24:16 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:172)
```

Comment: Hello Tatiana, how big is your data? Also how many partitions does df  have?

Comment: My data has 155MB and df has 1 partition.

Comment: can you try to repartition(8) maybe?

Comment: Oh, it worked now, thank you. Why it wasn't working with one partition?

Comment: Spark was trying to process all your data at once when you repartition data is splitted  hence processed in partitions take a look [here](https://medium.com/parrot-prediction/partitioning-in-apache-spark-8134ad840b0) for details

Comment: Yeah, I read it. It seemed to be the problem. I am used to run spark on Databricks, there I don't have to deal with these problems since the company has very powerful clusters.

Comment: Which part of the code you changed, @Miss.Saturn? Could you edit your answer to show where the @abiratsis' answer fitted?